# How to update the date value alone in a DateTime variable

Tags: java, datetime

I have a variable of datatype DateTime (org.joda.time.DateTime). I need to update the date value of the variable without modifying the time?

Is it possible to add days to the DateTime variable without modifying time? 
[Like how we do for Date (org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateUtils) variable using method DateUtils.addDays()]

Thanks,
Sasank

Comment: Have you checked the javadoc?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withDate%28int,%20int,%20int%29

From JavaDocs

**withDate**

```
public DateTime withDate(int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)

Returns a copy of this datetime with the specified date, retaining the time fields.

If the date is already the date passed in, then this is returned.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime d = new DateTime();
DateTime fiveDaysLater = d.plusDays(5);
```

This adds 5 days to your time. I hope this is what you are looking for.

The same works for plusMonths and more see: http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html